# Derivation of proper acceleration in terms of rapidity

Tags: special-relativity

In the [Wikipedia page for proper acceleration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proper_acceleration#Acceleration_in_.281.2B1.29D), an equation for proper acceleration in terms of rapidity is given as $\alpha = \frac{\Delta \eta}{\Delta \tau}$, where $\eta$ is the rapidity of the moving frame, and $\tau$ is the proper time, (the time as measured in the moving frame).  Does anyone know of a reference that contains a derivation of this?  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know a reference but it isn't too hard to show that proper acceleration is indeed $d \phi / d\tau$.

First start from the more common definition of proper acceleration which is $du/dt$.
Where $u$ is the proper velocity, $t$ is the coordinate time.

Applying the chain rule several times we get:

$$
\frac{du}{dt} = \frac{du}{d\phi} \frac{d\phi}{d \tau} \frac{d \tau}{dt}
$$

Now proper velocity in terms of rapidity is $u(\phi) = \mathrm{sinh}(\phi)$, so $du/d\phi = \mathrm{cosh}(\phi)$.

The Lorentz factor is $\gamma = dt / d \tau = \mathrm{cosh}(\phi)$.

After substitition the product of $\frac{du}{d\phi}$ and $\frac{d \tau}{dt}$ cancel, so you the proper acceleration is indeed the rate of change of rapidity with respect to the proper time.